# Can't handle post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to redirect using `res.redirect()` function. When I submit the form it should insert the data into the database and redirect me to home root. But the later is giving me this error:

```
Cannot POST /
```

this is my entire js file

```
const express =require("express");
const mongoose =require("mongoose");
const app=express();
const path=require("path")
const bodyparser= require("body-parser");
const Blog = require("./model/schema");
const { findById } = require("./model/schema");


app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set("views",path.join(__dirname+"/views"));
app.set("view engine","ejs");
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true}));


mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/blogdb", {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
.then(()=>
{
    console.log("Connection successful!");
})
.catch(err=>
    {
        console.log("Error: connection failed")
    })

    app.get("/",async(req,res)=>
    {
      const blogs=await Blog.find({});
      //console.log(blogs);
      res.render("blogdata/show",{blogs});

    })
    
    app.get("/create",async(req,res)=>
    {
        // const id=req.params["id"];
        // const eblog= await Blog.findById(id);
        res.render("blogdata/form");
    })

    app.post("/create",async(req,res)=>
    {
      await Blog.insertMany([
        {name:req.body.author,blog:req.body.blogcontent}
      ])
      res.redirect("back");
        
    })

    app.listen(3000,()=>
{
    console.log("Server is up and running");
})
```

This is all the file I have
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umHUC.png)
HTML form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/formstyle.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>create blog</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div><h1><b>Create your own blog!</b></h1></div>
    <div class="form">
    <form action="/create" method="post">
     <div class="name-in">   
       <label for="name">Author</label>
       <br>
   <input type="text" id="name" name="author" class="name" value="">
  </div >
    <div class="text-in">
   <label for="para">Enter your blog</label>
   <br>
   <textarea name="blogcontent" id="para" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="form" id="btn">Submit</button>
   <!-- <label for="text">Edit your blog</label>
   <input name="text" id="text"
   type="text"
   class="blog"
 value= "" > -->
  </form>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please mention why this is happening and is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you have an endpoint `/create` for the `POST` method, but the error says that you're trying to send the form to `/` on `POST`.
Make sure in your form that you add the correct `url` (meaning to add `/create`)

Comment: I have added the HTML form. URL means adding /create in action right?

Comment: It is giving 404  error in the console.POST http://localhost:3000/ 404 (Not Found)

Comment: You have to specify the entire link if it's not the same server. Usually you would use a global environment that contain that. So identify what's the address you're running your backend server at, the port of it and try to add them to the action: `action="host/ip address:port/create`

Comment: There is a problem with MongoDB query. When I commented insertMany() function it is successfully redirecting me to root. But I need to insert data into DB. Can you please check it?

Comment: I changed nothing and now it's working fine!!. 2 minutes ago it was giving me error for the same code .I commented it first and uncommented it later. I swear , the code is same . I don't know what to say anymore.